# Design of the layers of a Spring Boot RESTful API and its entities mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, rest

I have been thinking about the architecture of my server for days since I am developing my first RESTful API from scratch, with Spring Boot.
I am using Hibernate and I created several entities and its relationships using Hibernate/JPA annotations, however, I am not sure whether I should use these entities as the business models since they are "dirty" with the extra fields Hibernate would recommend.

[This is my tentative REST API layered architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epbxi.png)

This is an example taken directly from Hibernate's docs.

```
@Entity(name = "Person")
public static class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    private String registrationNumber;

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "person",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<PersonAddress> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

    // ...

    public void addAddress(Address address) {
        PersonAddress personAddress = new PersonAddress( this, address );
        addresses.add( personAddress );
        address.getOwners().add( personAddress );
    }

    public void removeAddress(Address address) {
        PersonAddress personAddress = new PersonAddress( this, address );
        address.getOwners().remove( personAddress );
        addresses.remove( personAddress );
        personAddress.setPerson( null );
        personAddress.setAddress( null );
    }
}

@Entity(name = "PersonAddress")
public static class PersonAddress implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Address address;

    // ...
}

@Entity(name = "Address")
public static class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String street;

    @Column(name = "`number`")
    private String number;

    private String postalCode;

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "address",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<PersonAddress> owners = new ArrayList<>();

    // ....
}
```

What I mean is, if I were to make a class diagram it would not look exactly as these entities because of the conditions you have to accomplish for Hibernate so it can map them to tables with ORM. For example, in a hypotetical class diagram `Person` would have a list of `Address`, not a list of `PersonAddress` as Hibernate suggests in this case (for mapping performance).

My question is whether I should separate the `Person` Model into two separate entities, one for the business logic layer (services) and one for the data access layer (repositories). Personally, I don't think that's a problem because Hibernate helps me ignore all the table creation, but maybe it's not a good practice and I should separate it into two different entities.

Answer (score 1):

In general I use an API-Model and an Entity- Model.
The api model is used to Exchange data between services and the entity object is used to persist the data. This keeps your architecture more flexible. If something in your busineslogic changes the entity is not automatically affected. Also sometimes you get data by the Client and don‘t want to expose the whole database object. So you can provide just the fields you need and complete the rest in the entity object. This is also recomended by static code analysis sonaqube.

Answer (score 1):

What you are referering to is a split between the persistence model and the business/domain model which is quite common. People often refer to this as the DTO approach.
The approach has many benefits and if you implement it right, almost no downsides.

Implementing it efficiently can be done with [Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) a library on top of JPA/Hibernate which will handle all the fetching for you transparently. Take a look at the [spring data integration](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.5/entity-view/manual/en_US/#spring-data-features) which allows you to get started very quickly or tryout a sample project through an [archetype](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#quickstart) to get a feeling for the benefits.